# Getting 403 (Forbidden) when try to load an S3 file from AWS CloudFront behaviour

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have created an S3 bucket. All objects are publicly accessible.

I can access the image file via S3 url: `https://S3_BUCKET_NAME.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xyz.jpg`

I can access the image file via CloudFront root url: `https://CLOUDFRONT_ID.cloudfront.net/xyz.jpg`

However, I can't access the image file via CloudFront URL's sub path: `https://CLOUDFRONT_ID.cloudfront.net/images/xyz.jpg`

I'm getting HTTP 403. I read lots of Stackoverflow pages to resolve this issue. However, I got stuck.

[error page config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ir3m.png)

[origin settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ws6d.png)

[list of behaviours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfzgm.png)

[s3 bucket policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dRLj.png)

Comment: It's a bit confusing, but yeah, the "Behaviors > Path pattern" field doesn't do what you think it does. I ran into the same thing a few months back. It does not add that path to the origin, not even with a separate custom origin for that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: i had to create a folder in s3 called "images" and I moved the picture into the images folder. it works

i also replaced path pattern from "/images/*" to "images/*"